# Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+ae^{bx})$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

As we know, $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$
when $|x|<1$, but what for a function $\log(1+ae^{bx})$? can we use it here?If not, then how'll we expand it?

Comment: You can substitute and then combine like terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln(1+ae^{bx})=\ln(1+a+abx+ab^2x^2/2+...\\
=\ln((1+a)(1+\frac{abx}{a+1}+\frac{ab^2x^2}{2(a+1)}+...\\
=\ln(1+a)+\ln(1+\frac{abx}{1+a}+\frac{ab^2x^2}{2(1+a)}+...\\
=\ln(1+a)+\left(\frac{abx}{1+a}+\frac{ab^2x^2}{2(1+a)}\right)-\frac{(abx)^2}{2(1+a)^2}+...$$ 
The last line is because $\ln(1+z)=z-z^2/2+...$

When $x$ is large, $$\ln(1+ae^{bx})=bx+\ln(a)+\ln\left(1+\frac{e^{-bx}}a\right)\\
=bx+\ln(a)+e^{-bx}/a-e^{-2bx}/(2a^2)+...$$

Comment: but how did you expand from 2nd to 3rd line, how can you say $(a[e^{bx}-1])/(1+a)$

Comment: isn't that only when $|z|<1$?

Comment: In the Taylor series, $x$ is near zero, so $abx/(1+a)$ is near zero.

Comment: I wonder if the result could be $$\log (a+1)+\frac{a b x}{a+1}+\frac{a b^2 x^2}{2 (a+1)^2}-\frac{x^3 \left((a-1) a
   b^3\right)}{6 (a+1)^3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$

Comment: Lol, there are so many dots that you can't even see the close parentheses because they are infinitely far away.